# How to avoid ambiguous references on nuget source code packages includeded in two projects with internalsvisibleto

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package, morelinq

Let's say you have two projects:

- Main.csproj
- Main.Test.csproj

And Main has an attribute

```
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("Main.Test")]
```

Now we want to reference a NuGet package that ships its content as source code such as MoreLinq (https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) in both projects.

The problem is that there are now two copies of the source visible to the Main.Test project and therefore the compiler spews an Ambiguous reference error.

Is there any way to avoid this without modifying the source code that the package drops into each project?

P.S. Please don't use arguments such as 'don't use InternalsVisibleTo because...'. I can read those points elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extension methods from morelinq will be public so if you have them in main.csproj, you won't need them in main.test.csproj but they'll still be accessible within main.test.csproj.

Comment: Great point! Complicating things to better reflect our use case: AssemblyX in NuGet PackageX depends on MoreLinq. Main and Main.Test both reference PackageX. Now both get MoreLinq source code by virtue of the dependency. The code we referenced (not MoreLinq) defined its members as internal (not public), but I realize now that this is irrelevant - the problem is with NuGet dependency packaging which led me to [link](http://docs.nuget.org/Release-Notes/NuGet-2.7#development-only-dependencies). This solves the NuGet issue. Your help on correct usage pointed me in the right direction - thanks!